# Webview doesn't load content/file from java http server

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2, java-server

I am trying to use javaFx for my application. I have a java server tested and running code, actually its a library that initiates server. I have problem loading file from javafx's webview.
Suppose the server is running on port 2345 then the following shows javafx's webview blank.

-- some code ---

```
Webview view  = new Webview();
view.getEngine().load("http://localhost:2345/sample.html");
```

---- some code ---

The content loads fine from the web browser but not from the javaFx webview.
What is preventing webview to load content/file ? My guess was that the webview load is instantiated before the server is started, so I worked with javaFx runLater but it didn't solve. Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: are you sure ":" sign after 2345 is a valid url? Can you open it in regular browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you have server with http through port 2345 you need to state it's name in advance to port:

```
"http://servername:2345/sample.html"
```

e.g. if you have server on the same machine:

```
"http://localhost:2345/sample.html"
```

Comment: That's true,  i 've been doing that...but still nothing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "webview doesn't load"? White screen? Can it load other sites in your program?

Comment: Yes i can load other sites from my program but i can't load localhost on some port started by server, but i can load the same url from browser...

Comment: Well the WebView was expecting the complete response from the java server. It was expecting Content-Type: text/html as well but the browser could understand without that. It took me a while to figure out. Hope this helps . Thanks for answering my question.